# How to initialize ol.Feature object's id or style property from the constructor

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm new to the Open Layers library and JavaScript in general. So I wonder why can't I specify the values of `id` or `style` properties of a Feature object through the `opt_geometryOrProperties` [constructor](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/apidoc/ol.Feature.html) argument. After all it works with the `geometry` property:

```
var g = new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]);
var feature = new ol.Feature({geometry: g});

feature.getGeometry() === g; // true
```

But if I try it with `id` or `style`, it does *not* work:

```
var g = new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]);
var id = 1;
var style = new ol.style.Style;
var feature = new ol.Feature({
   geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]),
   id: id,
   style: style
});

feature.getId() === id; // false
feature.getStyle() === style; // false
```

How do I tell which properties are settable through the constructor and which are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, you can't set the style in the constructor and it seems unlikely they are going [to add it to the constructor](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2274). Concerning where you can find what properties can be set in the constructor, see the [API documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/apidoc/ol.Feature.html).

Something that might be useful is to set the style in the layer of the vector layer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = 1;
var style = new ol.style.Style;
var feature = new ol.Feature({
   geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]),
   id: id,
   style: style
});
```

For my experience this don't work realy... I use :

```
var feature = new ol.Feature({
   geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]),
   style: style
});
feature.setId(id);
```